# Display multi line string in a div

Tags: html, jquery

I have a registration process and on the confirm details I'm trying to display the address entered but I don't seem to be able to get it to display correctly and I have tried other answers on the site but none seem to be working.

**Code**

```
console.log('compAdd_Passed_From_Func', compAdd)

$('#cdCompAdd').html(compAdd);
$('#cdCompAdd1.5').text(compAdd);
console.log('cdCompAdd', $('#cdCompAdd').val(compAdd))
console.log('cdCompAdd1.5', $('#cdCompAdd').val(compAdd))

$('#cdCompAdd2').html(compAdd);
console.log($('#cdCompAdd2').html(compAdd))
```

**HTML**

```
<textarea id="cdCompAdd" style="pointer-events: none; resize: none;border: none; overflow: hidden"></textarea>
<textarea id="cdCompAdd1.5" style="pointer-events: none; resize: none;border: none; overflow: hidden"></textarea>
<div id="cdCompAdd2" class="col-12"></div>
```

Ideally, I want to use the `DIV` but I initially tried and found an answer saying to use `textarea`

Looking at `devtools` the address is passed from my initial `function` to this `function` which populates all the fields on the page, is correct as shown below:

[image]

But this is what my actual page looks like:

[image]

This is the `function` that is populating my 'compAdd'.

```
$('#compAddressDetailsSection :input.address').each(function () {
    if (this.value != '') {
        compAdd += this.value + '\n';
    }
});
```

It does this as the user leaves the page and is working as shown above, but I can't get it to display as:

> Add line one
>
> Add line two
>
> town
>
> county
>
> BB1 1BB

Comment: Huum, in HTML `\r\n` do nothing.

Comment: change `'\n'` for `'<br>'`

Comment: @Bazaim - worked great. i actually tried <br /> but it displayed that in my `html`. can you mark it as an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you asked:

Just change `'\n'` for `'<br>'`.
Line break aren't displayed by HTML (until they're inside a `<pre>` tag).

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can output to a <pre>-container instead of a <div>. pre will honor linebreaks, indentions etc.

Answer (score 0):

Add this style to your div

```
white-space: pre-wrap
```

Answer from: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7781#issuecomment-502162034